# Why does my code keep loading new images?

Tags: jquery, image, base64

My code causes the networking tab of the browser to load endless base64 versions of these six images (I'm now trying them pre-loaded in hidden html elements, but there is no change)

**I don't understand why it is loading new images nor do I understand why they are base64 data.**

I am at times using `G.favicon_images[G.image_counter]` in my code to dynamically set other image src and noticing that the image appears delayed (because of the loading).

```
/*
            G.favicon_images=[
                'R/fav0001.png'
            ,   'R/fav0001.png'
            ,   'R/fav0001.png'
            ,   'R/fav0001.png'
            ,   'R/fav0001.png'
            ,   'R/fav0002.png'
            ,   'R/fav0003.png'
            ,   'R/fav0004.png'
            ,   'R/fav0005.png'
            ,   'R/fav0006.png'
                ];
            */
            G.favicon_images=[
                $('#fav0001').attr('src')
            ,   $('#fav0001').attr('src')
            ,   $('#fav0001').attr('src')
            ,   $('#fav0001').attr('src')
            ,   $('#fav0001').attr('src')
            ,   $('#fav0002').attr('src')
            ,   $('#fav0003').attr('src')
            ,   $('#fav0004').attr('src')
            ,   $('#fav0005').attr('src')
            ,   $('#fav0006').attr('src')
                ];
            G.image_counter=0;
            setInterval(function(){
                $("link[rel='icon']").attr({'href':G.favicon_images[G.image_counter]});
                $("link[rel='shortcut icon']").attr({'href':G.favicon_images[G.image_counter]});
                $("#lock_img").attr({'src':G.favicon_images[G.image_counter]});
                if(G.image_counter==G.favicon_images.length-1){G.image_counter=0;}
                else{G.image_counter++;}
            },333);
```

[image]

the html

```
<img id="fav0001" src="R/fav0001.png"/>
<img id="fav0002" src="R/fav0002.png"/>
<img id="fav0003" src="R/fav0003.png"/>
<img id="fav0004" src="R/fav0004.png"/>
<img id="fav0005" src="R/fav0005.png"/>
<img id="fav0006" src="R/fav0006.png"/>
```

Comment: Why would it stop? You start an interval that will cycle forever.

Comment: @Dave I'm wondering why the loading when they are already loaded? I know I have an Interval (I wrote the code.)

Comment: Are you sure it's actually re-fetching the image, or is it actually just getting a 304?

Comment: the status for each image is 200

Comment: Look at the Size column: `(memory cache)`. It's not doing an HTTP request, it's doing a `data:` request, which is succeeding. As for why they're base64, it's impossible to say without seeing the HTML.